# Add scrollPane to EditorPane(WebPage)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, null-layout-manager

I added a WebPage to my JFrame when we press a button (webpage opens in same Frame). It works fine. But I would like to add a scrollPane to it, but when I add the `JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jep);`(jep = JEditorPane) the webpage just won't show up.

I will add more info to this page if needed.

Code (main part)

```
            JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
            jep.setEditable(false);
            try {
                jep.setPage("xxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            } catch (IOException error) {
                jep.setContentType("text/html");
            }   
            jep.setBounds(100, 50, 150, 100);
            JScrollPane jsp = new JScrollPane(jep);
                            add(jsp)
                add(jep);
```

Thanks,  ~3751_Creator

Comment: Are you adding the JScrollPane to your JFrame?

Comment: For better help sooner, please post an SSCCE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is this Line:

```
jep.setBounds(100, 50, 150, 100);
```

You have set the bounds for `JEditorPane` but now you have added that `JEditorPane` to the `JScrollPane`. So instead of setting bounds for `JEditorPane` you should have use `setbounds` for `JScrollPane`.

---

*This all was about the reason for not showing up the JEditorPane.* But Now here a serious suggestion for you: **The use of setBounds are highly discouraged. You should use inbuilt layouts for aligning components in Swing. Java AWT and Swing has provided lot of useful layouts for such task . Look at [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to know about how to use these layouts.**